# Saving Icon to Hive DB in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

Can anyone help me. How to Save Icon in hive database in flutter. And to read it.

When I'm saving Icons it is giving error

```
unhandled exception: hiveerror: cannot write, unknown type: icon.
```

But when removing icon from hive database class and adapter it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by saving iconId instead of icon itself in the database..
In your model change the icon as

```
final int iconCode;
```

Now while saving icon, save it as

```
iconCode = selectedIcon.codePoint,
```

Now while displaying icon to the UI do something like this

```
icon : Icon(IconData( selectedIcon.iconCode,fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'));
```

Also, feel free to assign appropriate **fontFamily** and also provide the **fontPackage** if you are using icons from other providers such as fontAwesomeIcon

Answer (score 1):

To store an icon or an image in Hive DB, you need to convert them into bytes and save it as uint8List.

```
@HiveField(1)
Uint8List? icon;
```